# How can I redirect my domain to other one which I have no control over?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect

I have one domain (mydomain.com) I have control over - I can change its DNS records. There's another one which I don't control which is SaaS application (someexternalapp.com). What I'd like to have is to use application which is hosted on someexternalapp.com but to see it under mydomain.com.

I don't want to be redirected to someexternalapp.com every time when I type mydomain.com in my browser. I want someexternalapp.com to be completely masked.

Is this possible?

If so, how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes - it's possible, but depends if someexternalapp.com supports such configuration.
they'll need to add vhost for your mydomain.com.

only thing you need to do is to point your domain mydomain.com to someexternalapp.com

in ideal world you should use CNAME record but this might not work if your domain is literally something.tld, but it will work if your domain is something.somethingelse.tld [ eg www.whatever.com ]. your dns entry would look as follows:

```
 www IN CNAME someexternalapp.com.
```

[mind the dot at the end of the line ].

alternativly you can point directly to the ip of someexternalapp.com

```
@ IN A 11.12.13.14
www IN A 11.12.13.14
```

in this case - make sure someexternalapp will inform you whenever they change their ip.

you'll probably apply those changes via some web gui offered by your domain reseller - concept remains the same, but interfaces might differ.

there is also ugly solution html FRAME on mydomain.com hosted by you that someexternalapp.com but this might look suspicious from your client's perspective.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to pQd's answer, if your provider won't play ball with configuring a vhost for your domain (if they don't, I'd be *really* reconsidering their suitability as a provider) and you don't want to deploy an ugly frame-based solution, you can also setup a local HTTP server and proxy the content through to the SaaS provider.  This will produce a slower user experience and cost a chunk more in traffic costs, but it's another possible option.